# Hi how do I implement OAuth 2.0 for Microsoft exchange in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, apache-camel

The springboot application uses camel configuration and I want to implement OAuth 2.0 for connecting to mailbox of different application through Microsoft exchang using IMAPS protocol. How do I implement it.

I have the tenant id, client id, token value and token id.

Answer (score 1):

We added a component specific for that: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/others/mail-microsoft-oauth.html

And for the Spring Boot starter you can look at spring boot starter related to this component.

Comment: Both are same links

Comment: The approach is the same.